# How do I build 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system using npm?

Tags: windows, node.js, architecture, npm

I'm developing an application that I plan to distribute using [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), which only has 32-bit binaries on Windows. My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, so npm is building 64-bit binaries of [protobuf for node](https://www.npmjs.org/package/protobuf), which is a prerequisite of one of the modules I am using.

I have tried:

- npm install protobuf --arch=ia32
- npm install protobuf --target_arch=ia32
- npm set npm_config_arch ia32
- Installing the 32-bit version of node and npm and using it to install protobuf

And a few other things that I can't remember at the moment.

How can I get npm to build 32-bit binaries? Would I have to build it on a 32-bit machine?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to clone the repo into node_modules yourself and compile it manually using

```
node-gyp clean configure build --verbose --arch=ia32
```

inside the directory where you cloned the repo.

Comment: This worked, although my question was off-base :( My problem is not 32-bit binaries, but something else. I'll have to keep digging.

Comment: Semi-related: if you have to run node-pre-gyp, the option is `--target_arch=ia32`.

Comment: some more explanation please: where do I run this command? inside node_modules?

Comment: Inside the directory where you cloned the module's source code - I have amended the answer.

Comment: @asherkin I need wrtc package for armv7 arch. I am planning to give a try by downloading wrtc source in Linux-64 bit PC. Is it worth giving a try with your answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Add a file in your project root called .npmrc
Windows explorer doesn't allow creation of a file name starting with a dot, but this can be done on windows command line like this:

```
type NUL > .npmrc
```

Then add the following line to the file:

```
npm_config_arch=ia32
```

You may also want to put this line in there to force VS build version, since some packages want to use non-installed versions. Replace 2013 with your version of Visual Studio if different (2012, etc):

```
msvs_version=2013
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried the suggestion offered by asherkin and Derrick and suggest the below

```
npm set npm_config_arch ia32
npm clean-install --arch=ia32
```

The first command is to set the node environment of the project/folder to 32bit.
The second command is to reinstall all packages in 32bit.